# Color blindness helper algorithm

Tags: algorithm, colors, accessibility

What are some algorithms that help accessibility for colorblind people? I'm guessing color reduction could help, but honestly I can't find much information on the internet other than smartphone apps (not even papers).

**Rationale**: Recently, my CRT monitor stopped outputting magenta, so after a little research this seems to be a bit similar to how someone with tritanopia sees. Basically, anything in the red spectrum will be output as shades of blue. Although I could buy a new monitor, I'd like to know a software-based fix; this situation has got me interested in building accessible applications.

Comment: An accessible application does not rely only on colour. Also the form of icons will change, for example a green tick mark and a red cross.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: although it's nice that you live in an industrialized country and has spare cash to spend in electronics, this is not my reality and I'm pretty sure a few other billion are in the same situation as I am. Since there seems to be ways to reduce colors to the colorblind spectrum while maintaining contrast in order to improve accessibility, I believe it's a nice question to ask.

Comment: @Henry: Certainly. However, I'm looking for a filter-type solution that will work for any given raster image.

Comment: @stelonix: apparently you don't have humour in your country either! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to solve legibility problems for folks who are color blind is to increase the color contrast ratio. Web Content Accessibility Guidelines [require a minimum contrast of 4.5:1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#visual-audio-contrast-contrast) (3:1 for large text).

There are a handful of contrast analyzers out there. Google's [Accessibility Developer Tools](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/accessibility-developer-tools) includes algorithms for checking contrast and [recommending alternatives](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/accessibility-developer-tools/blob/master/src/js/AccessibilityUtils.js#L581).

If you were inclined, you could use this library to create a browser extension that dynamically changes CSS on a page to make content meet the required contrast ratio.